Python + Sqlite3 dump, source to MariaDB: Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci' (db noob)
I'm following Head First Python (3ed). I'm at the last chapter and have a bug I can't get past.
I've got an sqlite3 database that I need to port to MariaDB. I've got the schema and data in separate files:
sqlite3 CoachDB.sqlite3 .schema > schema.sql
sqlite3 CoachDB.sqlite3 '.dump swimmers events times --data-only' > data.sql

I've installed MariaDB via apt, granted privileges to a user, and logged in to get MariaDB prompt:
mariadb -u swimuser -p swimDB

source schema.sql;
source data.sql;

Now I run my python app locally that connects to the MariaDB but, and I'm not sure where exactly, the call fails with:
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1273 (HY000): Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'
Back at MariaDB prompt:
show collation like 'utf8%';      # shows no collation 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA;      # shows default is is utf8mb4 / utf8mb4_uca1400_ai_ci
At shell prompt, file -i schema.sql shows it's plain-text in us-ascii. I tried opening schema.sql and data.sql in notepadqq and saving them as utf8 but I still got the same error. I dropped the database and recreated it with:
CREATE DATABASE swimDB
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
    DEFAULT COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;

...then again sourced schema.sql and data.sql and still got the same error.
I saw a post where someone asked for this so...
MariaDB [swimDB]> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE VALUE LIKE 'utf%';
+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                         |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb3                       |
| character_set_collations | utf8mb4=utf8mb4_uca1400_ai_ci |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb3                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                       |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb3                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8mb3                       |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb3_general_ci            |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_uca1400_ai_ci         |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_uca1400_ai_ci         |
| old_mode                 | UTF8_IS_UTF8MB3               |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------+

So I guess there's a character set or encoding problem with the data (?).
At this point I'm lost, madly searching the interwebs for clues. Any help appreciated and sorry for the long post :)

Are you configuring your Python app to use the appropriate value for collation - is there perhaps some default configured that you need to change or override?

Could be. I don't have any explicit python code for collation. Wouldn't know where to start. There's just a dict I'm passing in to DBcm.UseDatabase( {
"host": "127.0.0.1",
"database": "swimDB",
"user": "swimuser",
"password": "xxx",
})

Maybe use MariaDB Connector/Python instead. utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci isn't supported by MariaDB - the newer utf8mb4_1400_ai_ci is. Recommend using this as the default collation on the database.

I added db.set_charset_collation('utf8mb4_uca1400_ai_ci') but I still get the same error. Tried db.set_charset_collation('utf8mb4') too. I'll have a look at MariaDB Connector/Python. Thanks.

Added to select statements too. SQL_SESSIONS = """
select distinct ts from times
collate utf8mb4_uca1400_ai_ci;
""" Same error.

Added "collation": "utf8mb4_uca1400_ai_ci" to connection dict and now I'm getting DBcm.CredentialsError: Collation 'utf8mb4_uca1400_ai_ci' unknown. :( But it's listed in show collation.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78859228/error-connecting-to-mariadb-from-python-unknown-collation-utf8mb4-0900-ai-ci (weird coincidence that both were posted about the same time).

Just tried MariaDB Connector/Python and it works. @danblack, if you want to post an answer, I'll mark this as answered.

MySQL Connector appears to be forcing a collation that does not exist in MariaDB (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci).
Per comments it appears that attempting to force a later MariaDB collation utf8mb4_uca1400_ai_ci on the connection appears to not resolve the connection.
MariaDB Connector/Python its actually tested with MariaDB server. Conforming to the Python Database API Specification v2.0 (PEP 249) it should be compatible with the MySQL (Python) Connector as a replacement connection module for your MariaDB server and application.
